# mapping for Elasticsearch percolator

Tags: elasticsearch

By default, my percolator mapping is like below

```
{
  "indexName" : {
    "mappings" : {
      ".percolator" : {
        "_id" : {
      "index" : "not_analyzed"
    },
    "properties" : {
      "query" : {
        "type" : "object",
        "enabled" : false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Assume document that I will percolate contains 'name' field which contains underbar

something like

```
{
name : "null_value"
}
```

and assume the query stored in percolator is like

```
{
"query":
    {"query_string":
        {"query":"name:\"null\"","defaultOperator":"AND"}
}
```

percolator returns this query, meaning this document matches this query.

but I want percolator to check if the field has exact value of coming document.

so if name:"null_value" then it should not match but name:"null" then it should match.

in this case, do I have to put mapping property to percolator? or do I have to use different query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have exact token match semantics you need to choose the proper analyzer for the "name" field. If you are not specifying a mapping, you are getting the default analyzer. Instead you should use not_analyzed.

Then on the search side you would want to use a term query. query_string is problematic as it get passed to the query parser before going through the text analysis pipeline.

Note, the method above is case sensitive. If you want to ignore case create a custom analyzer with a keyword tokenizer and lowercase token filter. Then on the query side use a term query, but lowercase beforehand, as term query is not analyzed.

Best Regards

Comment: Should mapping be provided in indexing time or in index creation time? It seems like during percolation, mapping for each document is generated automatically. So do I have to provided proper mapping for each percolation request?

Comment: It is best in most cases to specify a mapping when you create your index. When you percolate you specify the type/index which is where the mapping is derived.